# Why can you combine constexpr with const?

Tags: c++, c++11

The draft C++11 standard states that `constexpr` will declare an object as `const`:

7.1.5p9

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the
>   object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be
>   initialized.

So it seems that `constexpr const int i = 5;` is redundant. However, combining `const` is explicitly disallowed:

7.1.6p2

> const can be combined with any type specifier except itself.

Is there any reason why this rule wasn't extended to constexpr?